# Knockout.Js: Order of execution

Tags: knockout.js

So I'm trying to create filter for a project using knockout. The code for the filter is:

```
<div class="filter">
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: filterText, event {keypress:filterEntries}" placeholder="Filter Locations">
```

In the documentation for Knockout, it says to enable the default action as well I have to return true, shown here:

```
var ViewModel = function {
    this.filterText = ko.observable("");
    this.filterEntries = function(){
        console.log("filterEntries is being called");
        console.log(this.filterText());
        return true;
    };
};
```

Now the problem I am having is I am trying to make the text input update filterText first then call the function filterEntries instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyup` event fires after.

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
        this.filterText = ko.observable("");
        this.filterEntries = function() {
            console.log("filterEntries is being called");
            return true;
        };
  
        this.filterText.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: filterText, event: 
    {keyup:filterEntries}" placeholder="Filter Locations">
    </div>
```